# In some case solr not deleting unique key

Tags: solr

I am using solr4.10 version.I am using partially update for updating  and  deleting solr document using the following command for delete.

```
<delete><id>05991</id></delete>
```

All document is deleting properly, but what happens in some case all fields of a document is deleting except unique key. I used delta import same thing happened. I am not able to find out what exact problem is.

Comment: Is this in a cluster or standalone? Could be important for these kinds of cases. Also, are you definitely committing and did you check that your 'id' is what Unique Key defines in schema?

Comment: Please give some more detains about the schema used and with which client you are pushing your deletes.